# Move using spfx extension using getFileByID

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, pnp-js-core

i am trying below to move file from source to destination but always getting GUID as undefined

```
if (event.selectedRows.length > 0) {
          // Check the selected rows
          event.selectedRows.forEach((row: RowAccessor, index: number) => {
            const docRelativeUrlDest :string = row.getValueByName('GUID');
            const destinationUrl = this.context.pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl+'/Documents/'
            const docRelativeUrl  = row.getValueByName('GUID');
            sp.web.getFileById(docRelativeUrl).moveTo(destinationUrl);
          
             this.showToastr();
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `row.getValueByName("UniqueId")`.

Test result:
[image]